# Java Loop through pixels in an image?

Tags: java, image, dictionary

I'm trying to find a way to make maps for my 2D java game, and I thought of one Idea in which I would loop through each pixel of an image and depends on what color the pixel it was that would be the tile to draw.

e.g.
[image]

Is it possible to loop through an Images pixels? If it is, how?

Could you please supply me with some helpful links or code snippets?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Note that if you want to loop over all pixels in an image, make sure to make the outer loop over the y-coordinate, like so:

```
for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++) {
          int  clr   = image.getRGB(x, y); 
          int  red   = (clr & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
          int  green = (clr & 0x0000ff00) >> 8;
          int  blue  =  clr & 0x000000ff;
          image.setRGB(x, y, clr);
    }
}
```

This will likely make your code much faster, as you'll be accessing the image data in the order it's stored in memory. (As rows of pixels.)

Comment: What image class is this answer using?

Comment: BufferedImage IIRC. :)

Answer (score 10):

I think Pixelgrabber is what you looking for. If you have problems with the code please write a comment. Here is the link to the javadoc: [Pixelgrabber][1] and another short examples: [Get the color of a specific pixel][2], [Java program to get the color of pixel](http://www.roseindia.net/java/java-get-example/get-color-of-pixel.shtml)

The following example is from the last link. Thanks to roseindia.net

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class ImageTest
{
    public static void main(final String args[])
        throws IOException
    {
        final File file = new File("c:\\example.bmp");
        final BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);

        for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++) {
                final int clr = image.getRGB(x, y);
                final int red = (clr & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
                final int green = (clr & 0x0000ff00) >> 8;
                final int blue = clr & 0x000000ff;

                // Color Red get cordinates
                if (red == 255) {
                    System.out.println(String.format("Coordinate %d %d", x, y));
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Red Color value = " + red);
                    System.out.println("Green Color value = " + green);
                    System.out.println("Blue Color value = " + blue);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[1]: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/PixelGrabber.html  [2]: http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0257.html

Comment: So would that example get each pixel? or the pixel at 100,400?

Comment: No, this example just grab the pixel 100;40 for all you need a loop through all pixels. I think a double loop through image.width and image.height should work fine for your problem.

Comment: The PixelGrabber link is broken

Comment: @Asaph link is fixed

Comment: @TobiasSarnow Thanks!