# How can i make some image analyzing using android API ?

Tags: android

How can i make some loop that run on all the pixels on the image that i got from the camera ?

I want to be able to scan all the pixels and according to the RGB of some pixel i need to make some decision about the next activity that my application will make.

Comment: suggest you to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749895/java-loop-through-pixels-in-an-image

Comment: yes ... i saw this - but is there something that i can use from the android API ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know some android or java image libraries, maybe you can find what you want in one.

- [Android image filter](https://github.com/ragnraok/android-image-filter)
- [Android image filtering](https://code.google.com/p/android-image-filtering/)
- Jhlabs [pure java](http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/filters/index.html) and [Android](https://code.google.com/p/android-jhlabs/)
- [Javacv](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv)
- [JJil](https://code.google.com/p/jjil/)

I think you can use some C++ libraries too, like:

- [CImg](http://cimg.sourceforge.net/)
- [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html)