# Image overlay/comparison and pixel color change

Tags: java, javascript, image, overlay

I need to compare the pixels in two similar images, createing a saved third image where the pixels that are the same between the two are turned blue. The code also needs to check that the images are of the same size before beginning the comparison, and exits with an error to the console if they are not the same size.

Here is the code i have. i still need to overlay the two images and turn the similar pixels blue.

I need to use Filechooser.pickAFile but other than that i am completely lost as to how to go about it.

```js
// Karl Thomas
// kthoma34
// Mon @ 4:00

import java.awt.Color;

public class PP2kthoma34 
{
  
  public static void main (String[] args) 
  {
    // Original picture
    Picture p1;            // create the variable
    String fileName = FileChooser.pickAFile();
    FileChooser.setMediaPath ( fileName );
    System.out.println (fileName);
    p1 = new Picture( fileName );
    
    // Width and length of original picture
    int width1 = p1.getWidth();
    int height1 = p1.getHeight();
    Pixel[] pixelArray1 = p1.getPixels();
    System.out.println(pixelArray1.length + "pixels");
    System.out.println("");
    
    
    
    // Modified picture
    Picture p2;            // create the variable
    String filename2;
    filename2 = FileChooser.pickAFile();
    FileChooser.setMediaPath ( filename2 );
    System.out.println (filename2);
    p2 = new Picture( filename2 );
    
    //Width and Height of manipulated picture
    int width2 = p2.getWidth();
    int height2 = p2.getHeight();
    Pixel[] pixelArray2 = p2.getPixels();
    System.out.println(pixelArray2.length + "pixels");
    System.out.println("");
    
    //checking that the images are the same size
    if ((width1 != width2) || (height1 != height2)) 
     {
      System.err.println("Error: Image dimensions do not match");
      System.exit(1);
     }
    
    // Save Third image with similarities highlighted in blue.
    String filename3;
    filename3 = FileChooser.pickAFile();
    p2.write( filename3 );
  }

}// end
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help you out: [(Java loop through pixels in an image)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749895/java-loop-through-pixels-in-an-image)

It is an answered Thread about looping through an image with BufferedImage, thus you should be able to find plenty of explenation in the Java API (regarding use and functions)

In the answered thread it also shows how to set the pixel of an image onto a specific color.

Keep in mind, that all the stuff about the coloring from that thread should be customized to fit your needs.

I.e you have to create a third picture with the correct measurements first (again with BufferedImage), afterwards check the coloring of selected pixel in both pictures against each other, if they are a match, third picture gets that same pixel set to blue, if not, you do what you had in mind.

If you need more specifics just say the word and I will see what I can do for you.

**EDIT: (16.03.2015)**

The following is a working class that does exactly what you wand. I tried to comment everything out as clear as possible, but from experience I know that this is not always clear enough for others. Feel free to use this code in whichever way you want.

Quick Disclaimer though: You would have to change the package name to your own package and would need to create an Object of this class in your main.class. Coding as little as possible into the main class is always prettier and more efficient.

**Compare Class**

```
    package stackexchange;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class PictureOverlayTest {
    /*
     * Four variables, three for the wanted BufferedImages, one String for the
     * Path of the third Image, which does not already exist.
     */

    private BufferedImage image1;
    private BufferedImage image2;
    private BufferedImage image3;

    private String pathImage3;

    public PictureOverlayTest(String filePathAndName1, String filePathAndName2,
            String filePathAndName3) throws IOException {
        /*
         * Constructor in order to keep this method reusable and clean. Needs
         * three Strings. The paths and Filenames of all three images. Image 1
         * and 2 should exist already, Image 3 will be created if all
         * requirements are met. Constructor creates the first two buffered
         * images, sets all needed variables and starts the checkAndCompare()
         * method
         */

        File file = new File(filePathAndName1);
        this.image1 = ImageIO.read(file);

        file = new File(filePathAndName2);
        this.image2 = ImageIO.read(file);

        this.pathImage3 = filePathAndName3;
        checkAndCompare();
    }

    private void checkAndCompare() throws IOException {
        /*
         * This function creates the Color blue, compares the sizes of both
         * pictures and if they are the same, creates a third image. Then it
         * loops through the two images and compares each pixel. If the pixels
         * are the same, the third image gets a blue pixel at that point
         */

        Color blue = Color.blue;

        if (image1.getHeight() == image2.getHeight()
                && image1.getWidth() == image2.getWidth()) {

            image3 = new BufferedImage(image1.getWidth(), image1.getHeight(),
                    image1.getType());
            for (int y = 0; y < image1.getHeight(); y++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < image1.getWidth(); x++) {

                    int colorImage1 = image1.getRGB(x, y);
                    int colorImage2 = image2.getRGB(x, y);

                    if (colorImage1 == colorImage2) {

                        image3.setRGB(x, y, blue.getRGB());

                    } else {

                        // Whatever Color you want. By default it is black.

                    }

                }
            }
            savePicture3();
            System.out.println("Message: Image comparison is done");

        } else {

            System.out.println("Error: Image dimensions do not match");

        }

    }

    private void savePicture3() throws IOException {
        /*
         * This method saves the created Image into a file onto your computer.
         * The if() statement is used to check if the file was successfully
         * created, in order to avoid unwanted errors. Keep in mind, that you
         * have to change the "bmp" in ImageIO.write() to whatever format you
         * actually want
         */

        File file = new File(pathImage3);
        if (file.createNewFile()) {
            ImageIO.write(image3, "bmp", file);
        }
    }

}
```

**Main Class**

```
package stackexchange;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
            PictureOverlayTest test = new PictureOverlayTest(
                    "H:\\stackexchange\\file1.bmp",
                    "H:\\stackexchange\\file2.bmp",
                    "H:\\stackexchange\\file3.bmp");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: See the only problem with this is it used buffered image and not filchooser. I am no Pro at this, and am having significant trouble translating this into something that works. i was able to overlay one image over the other, now i just need to turn all the pixels that are the same blue.  Both of them are the same picture, only with some editing in a few places.

Comment: Edited my answer, hope my code example will be able to help you

Comment: Did my Edit help you with your problem?