# How can I superimpose two pictures together in Java?

Tags: java, image, colors, bufferedimage, image-manipulation

I'm trying to take two buffered images and superimpose one over the other.

For example, I want to start with this image as a base:

[image]

Then I want to superimpose this image on top of it:

[image]

To get this:

[image]

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, this is possible. What have you tried already?

Comment: I'm unsure but what you mean by "superimpose", but I guess mutiplying one by the inverse of another by intensity (dividing ...) may do the work. You can use any image processing library like OpenImaj or OpenCV :).

Comment: @akuzminykh I'm working with noise, so I've tried adding the two noise functions together, which obviously didn't work very well. I've also looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14241944/overlay-images-in-java which didn't help much, lol

Comment: @SamiTahri Can this be done without an external library?

Comment: @FudgeMuffins What do you mean by *"which obviously didn't work"*? You define a function that takes two grayscaled pixels and return the result. You don't need any external library for this. The standard Java `ImageIO` has already all you need for this.

Comment: @akuzminykh What do you mean by "Define a function that takes two grayscaled pixels and retuns the result"? I don't quite understand what you're getting at. I meant that I have two noise functions that I generate, and adding those two functions together did not produce the desired result.

Comment: @FudgeMuffins Those functions produce an *image*. An *image* consists of pixels. For each *(x, y)* you take a pixel from each image and apply a function on those grayscale values. The resulting grayscale value shall be the value for the *pixel* at *(x, y)* of the resulting *image*. *" [...] adding those two functions together did not produce the desired result"*, show this code. Don't just ask if something is possible.

Comment: @akuzminykh These functions are `noiseFunc(x, y) + noiseFunc2(x,y)`. That is what I meant by adding them together. The actual code of the function is irrelevant because all it does is provide the brightness of each pixel.

Comment: @FudgeMuffins To add them like that obviously won't work. :-D It's a little more complex than just `+` them together, not difficult though. You have to use a valid function for blending values. You can find those functions [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend_modes). I'd love to write a nice answer but as you refuse to post the fkin code so I don't have to open eclipse for *helping* you, it's waste of time. Anyways, check out how to blend values together and apply that on the values from your noise functions.

Comment: I'm not sure how "superimposing" these two images could give you that third one. The second image's values are clearly inverted in that final result. I'd expect something more like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqC3I.png) from combining those two.

Answer (score 0):

For image manipulation in Java Im4java might be a good choice, its a pure-java interface to the ImageMagick command-line. [This](https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=20251) might be something similar what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [ImageIO](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html). If you want to implement it on your own, then you can [iterate the pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749895/java-loop-through-pixels-in-an-image) of both images, call a function that you prefer to calculate the output pixel and [put it into the target image](https://www.dyclassroom.com/image-processing-project/how-to-get-and-set-pixel-value-in-java).

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in Imagemagick command line.

It is just an invert of the second image and then a 50-50 blend of the two image.

```
convert 1.png \( 2.png -negate \) -define compose:args=50 -compose blend -composite 1_2.png
```

[image]

For Java, you can use im4java and find the equivalent commands.